# Prime $Sun_{2}$-free bipartite graphs. Asked to prove a false statement?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have been asked to prove the following as an exercise:

"Let $Sun_{2}$ be the graph obtained from $Sun_{4}$ by deleting two vertices of degree $1$ of distance $3$ from each other. Show that every prime $Sun_{2}$-free bipartite graph is the bipartite complement of a regular graph of degree $1$."

Here is $Sun_{4}$:

[image]

I'm sure this is false. Take the graph $P_{4}$ as a counter-example. $P_{4}$ is clearly prime,  $Sun_{2}$-free, and bipartite, but it is the bipartite complement of **only** $K_{2}+2K_{1}$ (with the isolated vertices placed in different parts), which clearly is not $1$-regular. $P_{6}$ serves as another counter-example.

I am also appreciating, as I write this, that the bipartite complement operation is not well-defined. If a graph is disconnected and so admits more than one bipartition, each bipartition may result in a different bipartite complement. Could someone please verify this?

However this does not seem to resolve the exercise.

It seems strange to be asked to prove something which is so clearly false. Am I missing something?

Thanks muchly.

Comment: What's the definition of "prime graph" here? Is it the label-vertices-so-that-adjacent-vertices-are-relatively-prime definition? That doesn't seem related to anything else in the problem. (But I admit that $P_4$ and $P_6$ are both prime by this definition.)

Comment: Hi Misha, no the definition of a prime graph used here is that the graph has no non-trivial modules. That is for all strict subsets of the vertex set, consisting of at least 2 vertices, there is a vertex that distinguishes this set (has a neighbour and non-neighbour in the set). Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest looking at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11083-014-9333-9, especially Theorem 11, where the authors discuss the structure of these graphs.  Based on my cursory reading, there is probably at least a missing assumption in the exercise.